# Lemma 3.2 of "Catalan's Conjecture" by R. Schoof.

Tags: modular-arithmetic, proof-explanation, algebraic-number-theory, diophantine-equations

In the book *Catalan's conjecture* by R. Schoof, Lemma 3.2 on page 14 is the following:

> *Let $q\geq3$ be prime and let $x$, $y$ be nonzero integers satisfying $x^2-y^q=1$. Then we have $x\equiv0\pmod{q}$.*

The proof is about a page long, so I won't reproduce it in full, but it can be found [here](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781848001848) for example. He shows that $y+1=u^2$ for some nonzero $u\in\Bbb{Z}$, and that
$$x+y^{(q-1)/2}\sqrt{y}=\pm(u+\sqrt{y})^m,$$
for some $m\in\Bbb{Z}$. Then I quote (emphasis mine):

> Since the elements $1,\sqrt{y}$ for m a $\Bbb{Z}$-basis for the additive group of $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{y}]$, it follows that $mu^{m-1}\equiv0\pmod{y}$. This implies that $y$ divides $mu^{m-1}$. **Since $y+1=u^2$, Exercise 2.1 implies that $y$ is even and $u$ is odd.**

All is good and obvious, until the emphasized sentence. I do not see how it follows. For completeness; Exercise 2.1 is the following very basic exercise:

> Let $x\in\Bbb{Z}$. Show that $x^2$ is congruent to $0$ or $1\pmod{4}$. Shows that $x^2+2$ cannot be a square modulo $4$.

So my question is: How does it follow from Exercise 2.1 that $y$ is even and $u$ is odd?

Comment: Use Lemma 3.1 instead.

Comment: I think it's a typo.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I'd add that as an answer so it's removed from the unanswered queue and you get credit! I'd upvote.

Comment: Anyone care to explain the downvote?